How to unpack firmware .bin file
I need help to unpack or create python script to unpack automatically the type of this firmware, someone already unpacked this firmware, and it contains: boot.bin, aboot.bin and system.bin files. (possible to have others partitions in other firmware).
I analyse the firmware.bin with Hex Editor and i see on the Header the information of: size, offset and name of the partition.  I compare it with the extracted partiton files and i get this information:

"aboot"  size: 00 47 10 00 / offst partition address start : 00 00 8B 00
"boot"   size: 00 47 10 00 / partition address start offset: 00 07 6B 00
"system" size: 02 0A 00 00 / partition address start offset: 00 4E FB 00

i make some analyse and verification also that next offset or next partition address 'start' is getting on:  hex address inverse on black color ( + ) the offset of preview partition.
ex: to get the start partition of "system" : 00 4E FB 00 = 00 47 90 00 + 00 07 6B 00
_ partition size: red color  / length of byte who contains infos is: 1C, which starts with 01 for other partitions except the first or start of partition (aboot is 08)

So, i want to understand, where or how to know the offset of partition address start  because it needed to calculate the offset of next partition ?
Thank you very much.
(there is some  byte also in start of aboot 03 00 00 00)
sorry, if my explanation is not clear.
firmware link
